# Ant build successful but doesn't compile CSS, what could be wrong?

Tags: ant

I'm having a problem where the CSS isn't compiled at all.  Ant seems to work as expected, nothing happens with my CSS files though.

Can anyone help figure out why my CSS isn't compiling?

Here's the output from running `ant -v`

```
            $ ant -v
            Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on December 3 2011
            Trying the default build file: build.xml
            Buildfile: /var/www/testsite/build.xml
            Detected Java version: 1.6 in: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre
            Detected OS: Linux
            parsing buildfile /var/www/testsite/build.xml with URI = file:/var/www/testsite/build.xml
            Project base dir set to: /var/www/testsite/www
            parsing buildfile jar:file:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml with URI = jar:file:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml from a zip file
            Override ignored for property "TODAY"
             [property] Loading /var/www/testsite/www/build.properties

            BUILD SUCCESSFUL
            Total time: 0 seconds
            graeme@ubuntu:/var/www/testsite$ ant -v
            Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on December 3 2011
            Trying the default build file: build.xml
            Buildfile: /var/www/testsite/build.xml
            Detected Java version: 1.6 in: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre
            Detected OS: Linux
            parsing buildfile /var/www/testsite/build.xml with URI = file:/var/www/testsite/build.xml
            Project base dir set to: /var/www/testsite/www
            parsing buildfile jar:file:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml with URI = jar:file:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml from a zip file
            Override ignored for property "TODAY"
             [property] Loading /var/www/testsite/www/build.properties

            BUILD SUCCESSFUL
            Total time: 0 seconds
```

Here's my `build.xml` file:

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
            <project name="testsite.co.uk" basedir="./www">

                   <tstamp>
                    <format property="TODAY" pattern="yyyy-M-dd-hh-mm" locale="en,UK"/>
                  </tstamp>

                  <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties">
                      <classpath>
                           <pathelement location="/usr/share/java/ant-contrib.jar"/>
                      </classpath>
                </taskdef>

                <property
                    name="yui-compressor.jar"
                    location="/home/testsite/Downloads/yui-ant/lib/yuicompressor-2.4.2.jar" />

                <property
                    name="yui-compressor-ant-task.jar"
                    location="/home/testsite/Downloads/yui-ant/bin/yui-compressor-ant-task-0.5.1.jar" />

                <path id="task.classpath">
                    <pathelement location="${yui-compressor.jar}" />
                    <pathelement location="${yui-compressor-ant-task.jar}" />
                    <pathelement location="/home/testsite/Downloads/yui-ant/lib/rhino-js-1.6r7.jar" />
                    <pathelement location="/home/testsite/Downloads/znerd-optipng-ant-task-ff33669/build/optipng-ant-task.jar" />
                </path>

                <taskdef
                    name="yui-compressor"
                    classname="net.noha.tools.ant.yuicompressor.tasks.YuiCompressorTask">
                    <classpath refid="task.classpath" />
                </taskdef>

                <taskdef name="optipng" classname="com.pensioenpage.jynx.optipng.OptiPNGTask" classpath="/home/testsite/Downloads/znerd-optipng-ant-task-ff33669/build/optipng-ant-task.jar" />

                <property file="build.properties" />

                <target name="export">
                    <tar destfile="./exported_latest_update_${TODAY} ${TSTAMP}.tar" 

                        basedir="./" 
                        includes = "www/**"
                        excludes=".git/**, .gitignore/**, www/secure/images/categories/**, www/secure/images/content/**, www/secure/images/products/**, www/secure/images/widgets/**">
                        <date datetime="08/14/2009 10:00 AM" when="after"/>

                    </tar>
                </target>

                    <target name="css-frontend">

                        <property name="cssFilePath" value="./www/css"/>
                        <property name="cssUrlPath" value="/css"/>
                        <property name="frontendCss" value="build.frontend"/>

                        <delete>
                            <fileset dir="./www/css" includes="build.frontend.*.css" />
                        </delete>

                        <concat destfile="${cssFilePath}/${frontendCss}.css">
                          <fileset dir="./www/css" includes="reset.css" />
                          <fileset dir="./www/css" includes="text.css" />
                          <!--<fileset dir="./www/css" includes="forms.css" />-->
                          <fileset dir="./www/css" includes="tables.css" />
                          <fileset dir="./www/css" includes="vendor-logos.css" />
                          <fileset dir="./www/lib/javascript/fancybox2/" includes="jquery.fancybox.css" />
                          <!--<fileset dir="./www/css" includes="wp-panel.css" />-->
                      <fileset dir="./www/lib/javascript/jQuery.mmenu-master/dist/css" includes="jquery.mmenu.custom.css" />
                          <fileset dir="./www/css" includes="styles-2015.css" />
                      <fileset dir="./www/css" includes="loop54-styles.css" />
                          <fileset dir="./www/css" includes="feature_icons.css" />
                          <fileset dir="./www/css" includes="shopzilla.override.css" />
                          <fileset dir="./www/css/responsive-2015" includes="below-1100.css" />
                      <fileset dir="./www/css/responsive-2015" includes="below-1024.css" />
                          <fileset dir="./www/css/responsive-2015" includes="below-980.css" />
                      <fileset dir="./www/css/responsive-2015" includes="above-980.css" />
                          <fileset dir="./www/css/responsive-2015" includes="below-690.css" />
                          <fileset dir="./www/css/responsive-2015" includes="below-500.css" />
                      <fileset dir="./www/css/responsive-2015" includes="below-320.css" />
                          <fileset dir="./www/css/responsive-2015" includes="retina-screens.css" />
                        </concat>

                        <concat destfile="${cssFilePath}/build.wp-style.css">
                          <fileset dir="./www/css" includes="reset.css" />
                          <fileset dir="./www/css" includes="text.css" />
                          <fileset dir="./www/css" includes="vendor-logos.css" />
                          <fileset dir="./www/css" includes="wp-style.css" />
                        </concat>

                        <concat destfile="${cssFilePath}/build.checkout.css">
                          <fileset dir="./www/lib/javascript/fancybox2/" includes="jquery.fancybox.css" />
                          <fileset dir="./www/css" includes="reset.css" />
                          <fileset dir="./www/css" includes="text.css" />
                          <fileset dir="./www/css" includes="forms.css" />
                          <fileset dir="./www/css" includes="tables.css" />
                          <!--<fileset dir="./www/css" includes="wp-panel.css" />-->
                          <fileset dir="./www/css" includes="one-page-checkout.css" />
                        </concat>

                        <checksum file="${cssFilePath}/${frontendCss}.css" property="css_md5"/>

                        <property name="frontendCssMd5" value="build.frontend"/>

                        <move file="${cssFilePath}/${frontendCss}.css" tofile="${cssFilePath}/${frontendCssMd5}.css"/>

                        <yui-compressor
                            warn="false"
                            munge="true"
                            preserveallsemicolons="false"
                            fromdir="${cssFilePath}"
                            todir="${cssFilePath}/">

                          <include name="${frontendCssMd5}.css" />
                          <include name="build.wp-style.css" />
                          <include name="build.checkout.css" />
                          <include name="720plus.css" />
                          <include name="719minus.css" />

                        </yui-compressor>

                    </target>
            </project>
```

Comment: You have to say which target you want to run - otherwise no target does, just the tasks outside of targets.  Either add the target to the command line (css-frontend maybe?) or specify the default target as an attribute of the project element.

Comment: @martinclayton awesome thank you, got it working now.  If you want to add an answer I'll accept it.